# Webpage refreshes to top on incorrect form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

If I enter an Incorrect email address or password my site refreshes to the top of the page and I see this error

```
Incorrect email and Pass
```

I have to scroll back down to where my form is to see a detailed error.

I want to prevent my page going to the top.

I have searched for a solution on here but can't find anything.

HTML Code:

```
<body>

    <form method="post" style="margin-right:450px;">
        <table align="center" cellspacing="3px;">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input style="border:1px #666 solid; border-radius: 4px; width: 180px; padding: 12px 20px; font-size:18px;" type="email" name="mail" required placeholder="Your Email">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input style="border:1px #666 solid; border-radius: 4px; width: 180px; padding: 12px 20px; font-size:18px;" type="password" name="pass" required placeholder="Your Password">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <br><br>

        <button class="button button3" type="submit" name="log" style="color:#FFF; text-align:center; margin-left:70px;">Log In</button></td>

    </form>
</body>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","form_data");

    if(isset($_POST['log']))

    {
        $_SESSION['mail'] = $_POST['mail'];

        $email = $_POST['mail'];

        $Password = $_POST['pass'];

        $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from registration where (User_name = '$email' or Email= '$email') and Password = '$Password' ");

        $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);   

        if($check == 1)
        {

            echo "<h1> User Login <h1>";

            header("location:exam.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class='error'> ";
            echo "!! Invalid Username Or Password !!";
            echo "</div>";

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: You're doing the redirect using `PHP`, which is a serverside language, which means the function you use is working as expected and thus refreshing. You can either use `AJAX` to make the request and prevent the refresh, which is the better solution, or do a `Javascript` scrollTo to that section immediately after redirecting with `PHP`

Comment: You could use a fragment identifier in the form's target to end up on the desired part of the page. `<form id="rightHere" method="post" style="margin-right:450px;" action="#rightHere">`